# Best way of communication for embedded RPi

Tags: wireless, communication, wireless-adapter

I am using a raspberry pi as the brain of a mobile robot. For debug reasons I'd like to keep a wireless connection with a PC. Communication speed is probably not an issue here, but a little bit of headroom would be great.

Is there an easy-to-use wireless communication way that does (ideally) not need a self-built application running on the debug PC?

Important are:

- low power usage (the robot is running of a 3000mAh battery, so every mA saved is important)
- low processing usage (there will be some image processing getting on)
- ease of use
  (on the RPi on one hand, also on the PC - "open a website" is better than "write your own program")

I've looked into bluetooth, but I couldn't find an easy way to implement it on the debug PC. Also I considered the idea of using a wifi-stick with a simple web server running on the pi, but I can't really tell whether this will put a burden on the power and processing time.

Comment: Hello and welcome! I hope this question is not considered too broad...

Comment: Thank you, I hope so, I tried being as precise as possible.

Comment: A USB wifi dongle plugged in only when needed would work; the challenge is more if you need something which can be very passive until *remotely* activated.  An ESP8266 could implement a serial bridge, and you can play with sleep timing to save power, but remote wakeup may be tricky.  Something like bluetooth low energy would be great for remote wakeup but require more customization on the PC side.  Also, if you designing a battery powered *product* you probably shouldn't be using a pi to begin with, but something with a mobile- rather than set-top-box chip.

Comment: It's not gonna be a product, it's mainly for fun (but should be as good as its possible ;) ). Can you estimate what the impact on processing power would be with a wifi-stick & a server delivering a simple html?

Comment: I don't understand the constraints you are adding if the wireless is for debugging purposes. Just use a standard wifi dongle and ssh into the Pi.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how can I transmit information via ssh? I know how to use it as a remote bash, but not for communication. The Constraints are there because I'd like to have a system that does not interfere with how the rest of the robot works - basically, I will constantly be debugging the robot.

Comment: ssh allows you to login to the Pi.  It's up to you to decide how your application makes debugging information available.  Personally I usually send a signal to the application to increment/decrement the level of debugging information sent to a non-blocking pipe.

Comment: A wifi stick with the interface down should consume no processor cycles.  One running and not in promiscuous mode and not actively being talked to should consume little, unless somebody on the network is really hammering away with broadcast traffic (due to mis-configuration?)  The real problem is power - the PI can't switch USB ports off, so unless you can soft-shutdown the stick it may consume power regardless if used or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to allocate the extra resource for a server software to send these details to your chosen solution. It is unclear what you want to be sending over, just text data? Or image data too?

For Images, video streams, you can use a normal WiFi dongle, during debug mode plug it in and start your server. A simple Python web server that can push the data you need via a web browser over Wifi, images, text, and HTML. You can set it to run in 802.11a/b/g/n to tweak power and also you can set the TX/RX power to tweak the power usage on the dongle. You will need to do your own research on this.

For pure text debugging you can use the UART on the Pi. You need to disable the console out put first. Then you create a script, in any language you prefer that will dump data to the UART. Then to the UART you attach a transparent Bluetooth Serial Device (more power efficient than WiFi)(try and find BLE but the range is extremely cut down on BLE!). Basically you pair your PC with that Bluetooth Serial device and you get a virtual COM Port. Now you can connect to the Pi using Putty on COMx, over Bluetooth reading all the data on the console.

As mentioned before, debugging should only be used when you testing things out locally, so battery shouldn't play to much of a factor. When you done and happy, you then turn of all debugging platforms, servers, processor and peripherals - and let your robot do its thing. (You may let you logger run and save to a file to review offline, in the event things go wrong while you are in production mode)

Comment: As it would be useful to send images sometimes I'm probably gonna use the python server, thank you! Also, for pointing out offline logging, I hadn't thought about that.

Comment: No problem Luke - Years of software developing always boils down to offline logs :) Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE). You can get a dongle (pay attention that it is a BLE and not regular Bluetooth dongle).
As name already says - it is low energy.

Then I would setup an ad hoc network over Bluetooth connection. I have written a blog post about [that](http://www.japina.eu/?p=4).

You can use ssh with IP address set up by DHCP.

Comment: I'd really like to upvote this answer too, but I can't having not enough reputation. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Bostjan, if you upvote Luke, then Luke can upvote you. Then we form an unbreakable upvote loop and everybody is happy :) +1  for good tip with BLE.